# How to display custom html rather than external uri using webview_flutter_web in Flutter Chrome app?

Tags: flutter, uri

I'm targeting Chrome device in Flutter.

The code below uses [webview_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web/example) to display "https://flutter.dev" or any other URI that I specify.

How can I change this code to display HTML that I build dynamically/programmatically, such as "Hello World"?

```
  final PlatformWebViewController _controller = PlatformWebViewController(
    const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(),
  )..loadRequest(
    LoadRequestParams(
      uri: Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          _SampleMenu(_controller),
        ],
      ),
      body: PlatformWebViewWidget(
        PlatformWebViewWidgetCreationParams(controller: _controller),
      ).build(context),
    );
  }
}

enum _MenuOptions {
  doPostRequest,
}

class _SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SampleMenu(this.controller);

  final PlatformWebViewController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<_MenuOptions>(
      onSelected: (_MenuOptions value) {
        switch (value) {
          case _MenuOptions.doPostRequest:
            _onDoPostRequest(controller);
        }
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<_MenuOptions>>[
        const PopupMenuItem<_MenuOptions>(
          value: _MenuOptions.doPostRequest,
          child: Text('Post Request'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onDoPostRequest(PlatformWebViewController controller) async {
    final LoadRequestParams params = LoadRequestParams(
      uri: Uri.parse('https://httpbin.org/post'),
      method: LoadRequestMethod.post,
      headers: const <String, String>{
        'foo': 'bar',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      },
      body: Uint8List.fromList('Test Body'.codeUnits),
    );
    await controller.loadRequest(params);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`WebViewController.loadHtmlString`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/loadHtmlString.html).